# singleton lock renewal error when i upload multiple files on blob using blob trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Its my 30th time trying to figure this out :( i have an azure function with blob trigger. I got this error when i upload 5+ files with 45 mb average.

```
2020-08-07T06:13:56.240 [Error] Singleton lock renewal failed for blob 'func-eres-integration-dev/host' with error code 409: LeaseIdMismatchWithLeaseOperation. The last successful renewal completed at 2020-08-07T06:13:37.9Z (18340 milliseconds ago) with a duration of 221 milliseconds. The lease period was 15000 milliseconds.
```

trigger looks like this

```
  [FunctionName("ParseAndLoad")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("pbar-staging/{name}", Connection = "pbarBlobConnectionVault")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext exCtx)
    {
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have another function instance running with the same blob?

Comment: i have a function that download files from sftp and upload to this container but i disabled that function. even if i manually upload 5+ files i get this error.

Comment: Sorry Raas, I didn't get the same issue and didn't find a solution about this till now, but you can check your function and storage account's  location region, try changing them to the same region. If it works, tell me please.

Comment: So looka like a “Scale Out” is helping because due to my function’s internal computation it was taking long. Now that I scaled up n scaled out a bit. It seems to b working. Il write my answer if it is confirmed.

Comment: not getting leasing error but getting this error 
"The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met."

Comment: Are you using REST API?  Why you need HTTP header(s)? If you use that, add x-ms-lease-id header. Here is a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Lease-Blob?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: REST api is not involved. i am simply uploading blobs to the container and i am getting this error in the Blob triggered function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308525/azure-blob-error-storageexception-the-condition-specified-using-http-condition
explains something but may be its not applicable in my case as i am using BlobTrigger