# Azure blob trigger error :The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

Im using a **python azure function** to get the trigger from azure blob using below code

```
import azure.functions as func
def main(blobdata: func.InputStream):
    totalprocessingtime = time.time()
    filename=os.path.basename(blobdata.name)
    blobfilepath = str(blobdata.name).replace(str(filesystemName)+"/","")
    logging.error("blobfilepath: "+ blobfilepath)
```

When a file is uploaded in the blob got the trigger. But sometimes got below error. I didn't set and header or anything to connect the blob.(Using connection string in bindings settings). Any idea what is the reason for error?

```
Executed 'Functions.blobprocessor' (Failed, Id=91e051f4-4e19-4892-91bc-aa6921579ba8, Duration=77ms)
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.timeseries2sqlprocessor
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter 'blobdata'
 ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync(Stream target, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext, IProgress`1 progressHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobReadStream.DispatchReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.WatchableReadStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Task baseTask) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Blobs\WatchableReadStream.cs:line 40
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ConverterManager.<>c.<<-ctor>b__4_4>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\ConverterManager.cs:line 74
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ConverterManager.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<<AddExactConverter>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\ConverterManager.cs:line 213
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ConverterManager.<>c__DisplayClass20_1`2.<<GetComposition>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\ConverterManager.cs:line 439
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IConverterManagerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<<AsTyped>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\IConverterManager.cs:line 52
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.TriggerAdapterBindingProvider`2.ExactBinding`1.BindAsync(Object value, ValueBindingContext context) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\BindingProviders\TriggerAdapterBindingProvider.cs:line 217
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.TriggerWrapper.BindAsync(Object value, ValueBindingContext context) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs:line 496
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Triggers.TriggeredFunctionBinding`1.BindCoreAsync(ValueBindingContext context, Object value, IDictionary`2 parameters) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Triggers\TriggeredFunctionBinding.cs:line 56
Request Information
RequestID:4e02bac0-501e-006b-1e54-1b1ac2000000
RequestDate:Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:39:10 GMT
StatusMessage:The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
ErrorCode:ConditionNotMet
ErrorMessage:The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
RequestId:4e02bac0-501e-006b-1e54-1b1ac2000000
Time:2021-03-17T17:39:10.6470643Z
```

Bindings
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me under what circumstances get the error?

Comment: @singhh-msft  no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when you do a Blob `write` operation, the `ETag` of Blob is reset, let us say `0x8CDA1BF0593B660`. And, before it is triggered (with ETag value `0x8CDA1BF0593B660`), the blob is updated by another service and it's `ETag` is changed to `0x8CDA1BF0593B661`.

Now, when your Azure Blob triggered function app tries to read it (with ETag value `0x8CDA1BF0593B660`), it is not as expected and gets this error.

*This error situation is similar to [Azure Blob: "The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094089/azure-blob-the-condition-specified-using-http-conditional-headers-is-not-met) and [Azure Blob Error: StorageException: The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308525/azure-blob-error-storageexception-the-condition-specified-using-http-condition.)*

Fix for this can be (un tested), add `Access => if match = *` in your Blob Trigger Attribute:

[image]

Comment: how do i set the  if match = * in blob trigger.?

Comment: binding using 
"bindings": [
      {
          "name": "blobdata",
          "type": "blobTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "path": "Data/Processing/{uniqueid}.json",
          "connection":"connectionurl"
      }
  ]

Comment: this is what i expected. Im using KEDA to scale the object. So the file may be changed .How do i  read and write the file without etag ?

Comment: updated the question with bindings. How to set if match = * in binding

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration

in this link there is no way to set conditon

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same issue.

I applied Harshita Singh suggestion, and the parameter is caught by the azure function.
As shown in the image below:
[image]

The message will keep appearing but after a while the blob is triggered, I believe the problem is with the time to generate the logs from azure. This blog also helped: http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Improving-Azure-Functions-Blob-Trigger-Performance-and-Reliability-Part-2-Processing-Delays-and-Missed-Blobs.

At the end my function.json is that:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "your_path/{name}",
      "connection": "storage_account",
      "Access": "=> if match = *"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```