# How to read and write the file parallel in azure data lake gen2?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have an azure function service in kubernetes environment which is used to read and write the file into azure datalake storage gen2. When a new file written in the blob storage trigger occurred and read the file. And make some changes in file and write back to the storage. When multiple files are changes at a time multiple pods are generated in kubernetes and access the files. Do to the difference ETAG i got error from azure service

```
The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
ErrorCode:ConditionNotMet
```

What is the best way to  avoid  the ETAG change in read and write operation?

Below is my code
Read binding configuration [trigger binding link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration)

```
def main(blobdata: func.InputStream):
    print(blobdata.name)
```

Write operation

```
def set_file_content(self, file_path: str, data: Union[str, bytes, bytearray]) -> None:
        file = DataLakeFileClient(
            account_url=self.account_url,
            credential=self.account_key,
            file_system_name=self.fs_name,
            file_path=file_path) 
        file.upload_data(data, length=len(data), overwrite=True)
```

I see some article based on the Etag configuration,

[Azure Blob Error: StorageException: The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308525/azure-blob-error-storageexception-the-condition-specified-using-http-condition.)

How do i set Etag in read and write operation?

I tried to set in write operation as below, But  something  is missing.Got an error `condition not specified`

```
file.upload_data(data, length=len(data), overwrite=True,etag="*",match_condition="IfPresent")
```

Comment: If the content changes, ETAG will change, which is its characteristic. Why should you avoid ETAG changes?

Comment: I mean that , How do  i read and write azure blob parallel ?